# Pop up tutorial page like Photosynth's

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to create something that is basically a clone of what photosynth does for their tutorial page.  A small "?" button pops up what looks like a new view in a frame that is slightly smaller than the first view, so that you can still see the first view around the edges.

[image]

It's a little tough to see from the pic above, but the part around the edges is the old view that the tutorial display popped up over.

My first guess is that I need to use a container view somehow, but I can't find anything on the web about exactly how to do this.  I can currently create a container view, hook it up to a new view controller via a segue, and do whatever I want in that new view controller, but the container view is always visible on the view it is contained within.  Any help?

BTW, I'm using storyboarding with ARC.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a transparent view to the key window, add a tap gesture recognizer that would dismiss it and the subviews to show the content:

```
#define OVERLAY_TAG 997
-(void)showTutorial
{
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    overlay.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [keyWindow addSubview:overlay];
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self                                                                
        action:@selector(dismissTutorial)];
    CGFloat border = 10;
    CGRect frame = overlay.bounds;
    // 20 is the status bar height (sorry for using the number)
    frame = CGRectMake(border, border + 20, frame.size.width - border * 2, frame.size.height - border * 2 - 20);
    // the black view in the example is probably a scroll view
    UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    blackView.alpha = 0.0;
    [overlay addSubview:dimView];
    // add all the subviews for your tutorial
    // make it appear with an animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{dimView.alpha = 1;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){[overlay addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];}];
}

-(void)dismissTutorial
{
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *overlay = [keyWindow viewWithTag:OVERLAY_TAG];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         overlay.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [overlay removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

This way you would remove the tutorial with a simple tap but you can use a button for instance.

Comment: You might need to remove the tapGestureRecognizer from the overlay view if you want the original view to be interactive again after the overlay was dismissed. Other than that it works nicely.